# Why does TextField lose focus when views are added around it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a simple screen with a `TextField`. There is one info text above it and one below it. Those info texts are displayed only when a certain condition is met.

Minimal example:

```dart
class FooPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<FooPage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  bool show = true;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() => show = controller.text.length < 5);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          show ? const Text("hello1") : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          TextField(controller: controller),
          show ? const Text("hello2") : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the info texts either appear or disappear, the `TextField` **loses focus**! If I use just one text (either of them), everything works fine.

---

I can solve this by wrapping the info texts with `ExcludeFocus` or using `autoFocus: true` on the `TextField`. But I am pretty sure those are not good solutions. At least the latter one can't be :)

What is happening here? What is the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why my solution works, but if you pass a GlobalKey to the TextField, it won't lose its focus.

```
GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();


TextField(controller: controller, key: globalKey,),
```

Maybe something to do with this? From the docs:

Widgets that have global keys reparent their subtrees when they are moved from one location in the tree to another location in the tree. In order to reparent its subtree, a widget must arrive at its new location in the tree in the same animation frame in which it was removed from its old location in the tree.

Comment: Ah ah, your answer brought me to this post that might explain why it loses state when it moves around https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433202/6176817. Hm hm.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why `ExcludeFocus` works though. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Went with your solution in the end :)